# Fitting 1.5" tapered fork in a 42mm head tube?

Tags: road-bike, headset

TL;DR: is there an IS42 bottom headset for a 1.5" tapered steerer tube?

I have a 2013 Giant Defy 3 road bike with a broken fork.  It's very hard to find used forks for this because the steerer tube needs to be 298mm long.  The inner diameter of the head tube is 42mm top and bottom and it has an integrated headset.  The original fork was 1.25" top and 1.25" bottom.  I found a good deal on a tapered carbon fork which is 1.25" top and 1.5" bottom.  Is there any headset bottom that will make this work?  All the IS42 headsets I have found are for 30mm bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Crane Creek makes a headset that will solve this problem. I've used it on my MTB and it works well. It does slightly increase the stack height.

[Do I need a tapered head tube to use a tapered fork on my bike](https://www.canecreek.com/FAQ/need-tapered-head-tune-use-tapered-fork-bike/)

Comment: Which headset are you referring to? I don't understand the relevance of that link, given the specs of my bike written in the question.

Comment: $80 for a headset might make the OP's "good deal" for a fork not so good though.

Comment: $80 might be ok. The Giant official replacemt fork is $300. But I think my new plan is to buy a devolution baseplate and then I can use a much more common 1.125" straight fork.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not going to be able to run a lower bearing for a 1.5" tapered fork.

In order for an integrated headset to remain (and therefore not alter the stack height) your lower headset would need to be 52mm to safely accommodate a 1.5" tapered fork.